# *#7284# not launching phoneutil

Tags: tablet, usb-connection-mode, dialer-codes

My tablet is not getting connected through USB.

It's showing me the error" "*USB device not recognised*"

On one forum I read to dial `*#7284#` and it will launch Phoneutil.

But in my case it's not working.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the device you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the code is specific for Samsung devices. Therefore, if your device is made by another manufacturer, it doesn't work (if the manufacturer hasn't added it specifically).

Comment: My device is of Ployer. So, is there any other way.?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Seems that PhoneUtil is a Samsung-only thing.